# How do I repeat this process for different values or cases?

Tags: python-3.x, loops

How can I use `for` loop here for multiple cases:

```
s=int(input())
a=[]
for j in range(0,s):
  b,n = map(int, input().split())
  for i in range(b,n+1):
    c=i*(-1)**i 
    a.append(c)
  print(sum(a))
```

I want the output such like:

input

```
5
1 3
2 5
5 5
4 4
2 3
```

Output

```
-2
-2
-5
4
-1
```

but when I use the `for` loop, I get a result like this:

```
5
1 3 
-2 
5 5 
-7
2 5
-9
7 5
-9
1 5
-12
```

Comment: without using first for loop i get the right answer for a single case but problem occurs repeat this for multiple cases.

Answer (score 0):

You have made a very small error in your code. To get the results you want you would need to use

```
s=int(input())
for j in range(0,s):
  a=[]
  b,n = map(int, input().split())
  for i in range(b,n+1):
    c=i*(-1)**i 
    a.append(c)
  print(sum(a))
```

In this case you reset the value of the array `a` in each outer loop instead of persisting it through the whole program.

You can check the results of the same on this TIO link [here](https://tio.run/##Rc5BCsIwEAXQfU7xl0msxdp2I@Qk4iLWqiN2OjTpwtPHNAguhvkMvM/IJz5nblMKjjhqYlmjNkbd5wUvEGPx/Bj1oQrmpADvzpe8rhXDYfKSQazwU3WQNxUNbJ7@PoNdUxqAwZHV@8ZYSygHX3uRkW962KQs2yNhnbQ3JqVeNWjVEb3q83Tocm6/). The output is as expected for the example provided